# IN statement are in order wise in salesforce?

Tags: apex

Actually i want to get record as per order by using IN statement like

```
List<Account> lstAcc = [Select id 
                          from Account 
                         where name IN('Rahul', 'Gaurav', 'Saam') LIMIT 1000];
```

i expected that it will provide firsty all account id having name 'Rahul' and than 'Gaurav' and so on ...

Comment: Based on Name specified in IN statement It will not query. It will check all the name if exist in your query it will return that

Answer (score 2):

It will not maintain the record order based on IN operator. It will just return an list(un-order) records. You can use List , Set , Map.keySet with "IN" operator in query, still it wont return the things in Order. You can use order by if you need datalist in particular order.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Name specified in IN statement It will not query. 
It will check all the name if exist in your query it will return that

Use **order by Name**

```
List<Account> lstAcc = [Select id 
                          from Account 
                         where name IN('Rahul', 'Gaurav', 'Saam') 
                         ORDER BY Name LIMIT 1000];
```